# What is the command line command that shows a list of available updates?

Tags: updates

When I SSH into a machine, when updates are available I get a message like:

```
15 packages can be updated. 
1 update is a security update.
```

What’s the command line call that will give me the same information?

Comment: `sudo apt list --upgradeable`  but what information are you after?

Comment: Exactly what I posted.  The number of packages and security updates as posted when I login. apt-check does what I’m looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```